# Django есть категории и в ней есть объекты как из категории ссылаться на отдельный объект. Буду очень благодарен

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
def home_page(request):
    pizza = Pizza.objects.all()
    category = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index/index.html',{'pizza': pizza, 'category': category})

def one_category(request,category_id):
    pizza_cat = Pizza.objects.all()
    category_cat = Category.objects.all()
    one_category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
    pizza = one_category.pizza_set.order_by('title')
    context = {'one_category' : one_category, 
    'pizza':pizza,'pizza_cat':pizza_cat,'category_cat':category_cat}
    return render(request, 'index/category.html',context)


#Шаблон:
{%for cat in category%}
   <div class="one_of_category">
     <img class="category_image" src="{{cat.img.url}}"/>
  <div class="desscriptions">
      <h1>{{cat.title}}</h1>
      <p>{{cat.text}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons_about">
      <a href ="{% url 'index:category' cat.id %}">More Information</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  {%endfor%}
  </div>


  {%endblock%}

  #и Вот тут загвоздка в кнопке View не пойму как сделать ссылку на отдельный объект : 
  {%for piz in pizza%}

  <div class="one_of_pizza">
    <img class="pizza_image" src="{{piz.img.url}}"/>
     <div class="desscription-pizza">
      <h1>{{piz.title}}</h1>
      <p>{{piz.text}}</p>
      <p>{{piz.id}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons_buy_view">
    <a href ="#"><button><span class="spna-button">Buy</span><span class="material-symbols- 
    outlined">shopping_bag</span></button></a>
    <a href ="{url 'index:one_pizza' piz.id}"><button><span class="spna-button">View</span> 
   <span class="material-symbols-outlined">info</span></button></a>
  </div>
</div>
 {%endfor%}


 </div>


{%endblock%}

#вот urls.py 
urlpatterns = [
path('', home_page, name = 'home_page'),
path('category/<int:category_id>', one_category, name='category'),
path('category/<int:category_id>/<int:pizza_id>',one_pizza, name='one_pizza')

]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)